# PowerShell unable to get file metadata from Comments field when it's too long

Tags: powershell

I want to extract some xml data from the Comments metadata field in .WMA files.
I'm using a script from Technet's Scripting Guy column to get all metadata, and it lists every attribute except the Comments field!

Some research by my colleague showed that when we shortened the data in the Comments field to < 1024 bytes, the data from the Comments field lists out fine.

It seems to me that the limitation is in the Shell.Application object; it just returns an empty Comments field when the contents is more than 1024 characters. Also, instead of listing every attribute, I just get the Comments, which is number 24.

The sample file I have contains 1188 bytes, and I think files will be aruond there, so it's not over by much.

Here is the script I'm currently running (removed comments for brevity):

```
Function Get-FileMetaData 
{   
 Param([string[]]$folder) 
 foreach($sFolder in $folder) 
  { 
   $a = 0 
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder) 

   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) 
    {  
     $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT 
     $hash += @{"Filename"  = $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 0)) } 
     $hash += @{"My Comment field"  = $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 24)) } 
     $hash += @{"Length" = $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 24)).Length }
     $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash 
     $hash.clear()  
    } #end foreach 

     $a=0 
     $FileMetaData 

  } #end foreach $sfolder 
} 

Get-FileMetaData -folder "C:\DATA\wma" | fl
```

Is there another approach I can use that will allow me to extract the full XML data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use the taglib-sharp dll from http://taglib.org/

here I copy the content of a 156 KB file to the comment  :

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("c:\temp\taglib-sharp.dll")
$data=[taglib.file]::create('c:\mp3\01. Stromae - Alors On Danse.mp3')
$data.Tag.Comment = (gc c:\temp\IMP_ERR.LOG)
$data.Save()
```

verification :

> PS>$data=[taglib.file]::create('c:\mp3\01. Stromae - Alors On
>   Danse.mp3') PS>$data.tag.Comment.length / 1KB
>   PS>155,2197265625

**edit**
I was able to use same code for a wma file

Comment: ..I still want to contact Jeffrey Snover and rant about it.. ;)

Comment: Want to just comment that the script has been chugging away in production for almost a year and has plucked apart the metadata from more than 400,000 .wma files using this library. It works flawlessly! Thanks again! :)